# pass csrf token to blueimp fileupload

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, csrf, blueimp

I'm building a SPA (Single Page Application) using AngularJS, and for FileUpload I'm trying to use Blueimp File Upload. Server side is in NodeJS, using csrf so all requests would be sent to the server with csrf token (X-XSRF-TOKEN set by AngularJS). Now when I'm trying to upload the file using Blueimp it fails with

> "Error: invalid csrf token"

as it dint attach the necessary token in the request, now I'm wondering on how to set the token. Please note that I'm already using AngularJS, and I dont have any meta tag set to csrf, but the token is available in the cookies.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it by using the following:

> ```
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     headers: {
>         'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN")
>     }
> });
> ```

Thanks

Comment: The risk here is that this sets it for all xhr requests, meaning you could leak the token to a 3rd party if you make an xhr request to them.

Comment: Great, thx. This saved my day! You can protect yourself by adding the line directly in tha ajax request so that the header is only valid for this special request.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbled upon this page like me, it should be

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN")
    }
});
```

CSRF instead of XSRF.

Comment: The risk here is that this sets it for all xhr requests, meaning you could leak the token to a 3rd party if you make an xhr request to them.

Answer (score 0):

Additional form data including the CSRF token can be passed along with the upload request via the `formData` option on the fileupload plugin.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata

```
$('#whatever').fileupload({
            url: '/Document/Upload'
            paramName: 'file',
            dataType: 'json',
            pasteZone: null,
            formData: [{
                name: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN',
                value: getAntiCSRFToken()
            }]
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you can write an interseptor that sets the token in the request header:
[AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: AngularJS part is working fine, I need to set the same before the file upload, I think in jquery FileUpload (jquery ajax). any ideas?